# Limiting the number of concurrent mappers in Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, sqoop, mapper

I want to run a Sqoop job with 100 mappers ("-m 100") - this would distribute the data into 100 partitions. At any point in time I want to limit the number of mappers running concurrently to 10. What is the property to do that?

The following did not work -

```
-D mapreduce.job.running.map.limit=10
-D mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=10
-D mapreduce.job.maps=10
-D yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores=10
```

Comment: There is possibility of using `org.apache.sqoop.repository.jdbc.maximum.connections=10` in sqoop.properties

Answer (score -1):

`Fair Scheduler` can be used to limit the number of concurrent map tasks in a job.

Add the fair scheduler to class path.Then set the following property in mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.jobtracker.taskScheduler</name>
  <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FairScheduler</value>
</property>
```

The configuration of fair scheduler will be available in two files. `mapred-site.xml` takes care of the algorithm parameters and `fair-scheduler.xml` takes care of pool configuration,running job limits etc

`maxMaps` and `maxReduces` will help us to set the maximum concurrent task slots.

Comment: I see that 
`mapreduce.jobtracker.taskscheduler=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobQueueTaskScheduler
yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.fair.FairScheduler`